# First HTTP Request taking a long time in JMeter

Tags: java, performance, http, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a couple of HTTP Request setup for my Thread Group. I noticed that the first request is always taking longer than any other requests. I reordered my requests and the problem still persists. 
This is making it hard to analyse the response time.

Is it a known problem with JMeter? Is there a work around?

This is the setup that I have

```
org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup@69bb01
org.apache.jmeter.config.ConfigTestElement@b3600d
org.apache.jmeter.sampler.DebugSampler@67149d
https: 1st request
Query Data: 
https: 2nd request
Query Data: 
Query Data: 
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@11b53af
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@11308c7
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@a5643e
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@585611
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser@1e8f4b9
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@11ad922
org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector@1a56999
```

Comment: Is the resource you're hitting being cached, causing the second request to return faster?

Answer (score 3):

This could well be because

> Servers usually need a warm-up before they reach their full speed:
>   this is particularly true for the Java platform where you surely don’t
>   want to measure class loading time, JSP compilation time or native
>   compilation time.

http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/

Are you allowing for some warm-up traffic to the servers under measurement first, to allow things to get in cache, JSP pages to compile, the database working set to be in memory, etc?