# JMeter - first sample in each thread is slow, and problem repeats every ~210s later

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, java-threads

I have a simple JMeter experiment with a single Thread Group with 16 threads, running for 500s, hitting the same URL every 2 seconds on each thread, generating 8 requests/second.  I'm running in non-GUI (Command Line) mode.  Here is the .jmx file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l66ksukyabovghk/TestPlan_025.jmx?dl=0

Here is a plot of the result, running on an AWS m5ad.2xlarge / 8 cores / 32GB RAM (I get the same behavior on VirtualBox Debian on my PC, very large Hetzner server, Neocortix Cloud Services instances):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtp6oqy0xtuybty/aws.png?dl=0

At the beginning of the Thread Group, all 16 threads report a long response time (0.33s), then settle in to a normal short response time (<0.1s).  I call this the "Start of Run" problem.
Then about 220s later, there is another burst of 16 long response times, and yet another burst at about 440s.  I call those the "Start of Run Echo" problem, because they look like echoes of the "Start of Run" problem.  The same problem occurs if I introduce another Thread Group with a delay, say 60s.  That Thread Group gets its own "Start of Run" problem at t=60s, and then its own echos at 280s and 500s.

These two previous posts seem related, but no conclusive cause was given for the "Start of Run" problem, and the "Start of Run Echo" problem was not mentioned.

[Jmeter - The time taken by first iteration of http sampler is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439557/jmeter-the-time-taken-by-first-iteration-of-http-sampler-is-large/25442382)

[First HTTP Request taking a long time in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982428/first-http-request-taking-a-long-time-in-jmeter)

I can work around the "Start of Run" problem by hitting a non-existent page with the first HTTP request in each thread, getting a 404 Error, and filtering out the 404's.  But that is a hack, and it doesn't solve the "Start of Run Echo" problem, which is not guaranteed to hit the non-existent pages.  And it introduces "holes" in the delivered load to the real target pages.

Update:  After suggestion from Dmitri T, I have installed JMeter 5.3.  It has default value httpclient4.time_to_live=60000 (60s), and its output matches that:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfcqhlfq2h5asnz/hetzner_60.png?dl=0

But if I increase the value of httpclient4.time_to_live=600000 (600s), it does not push all the "echoes" out past the end of the run.  It still shows echoes at about 220s and 440s, i.e. the same original behavior that I am trying to eliminate.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/if3q652iyiyu69b/hetzner_600.png?dl=0

I am wondering if httpclient4.time_to_live has an effective maximum value of 220000 (220s) or so.

Thank you,
Lloyd

Comment: So you want consistent performance? Have you looked at the GC logs?

Answer (score 2):

The first request will be slow due to [initial connection establishment](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-connection-establishment/) and [SSL handshake](https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/ssl-handshake-explained-4dabb87cdce)

Going forward JMeter will act according to its [network properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) in particular:

- `httpclient4.time_to_live` - TTL (in milliseconds) represents an absolute value. No matter what, the connection will not be re-used beyond its TTL.
- `httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration` - Reset HTTP State when starting a new Thread Group iteration which means closing opened connection and resetting SSL State

also it seems that you're using kind of outdated JMeter version which is 5 years old, [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3) (or whatever is the latest stable version available from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as you might be suffering from a JMeter bug which has been resolved already.

It might also be the case you need to perform OS and JMeter tuning, see [Concurrent, High Throughput Performance Testing with JMeter](https://howtojboss.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/concurrent-high-throughput-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) for example problems and solutions

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with a response to your suggestions.